# How to customize Google GetCurrentLocation Access Message in ionic V1?

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework

When I open my ionic app which has a functionality that get current location, it displays below message.

[image]

I want to add some more message on this notification as like this.

[image]

For some reason, Apple don't allows current our app until adding some more information on this notification dialog.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use **cordova-plugin-googlemaps** then this describes optional variables for the plugin: [Quick install with optional variables](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps#quick-install)

If you are using **cordova-plugin-geolocation** then this is what you do: [iOS Quirks: Usage description for location permission](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation#ios-quirks)

*The text from the link:*

**iOS Quirks**

Since iOS 10 it's mandatory to provide an usage description in the info.plist if trying to access privacy-sensitive data. When the system prompts the user to allow access, this usage description string will displayed as part of the permission dialog box, but if you didn't provide the usage description, the app will crash before showing the dialog. Also, Apple will reject apps that access private data but don't provide an usage description.

This plugins requires the following usage description:

- **NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription** describes the reason that the app
  accesses the user's location.

To add this entry into the info.plist, you can use the edit-config tag in the config.xml like this:

```
<edit-config target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
    <string>need location access to find things nearby</string>
</edit-config>
```

Comment: Thank you very much